# On click scroll to the top with 100px more

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use one page website and when I click menu button about it scrolls down to the top of some div... But Because I am using fixed header scrolling goes to 0px top and I need like 100px top like padding in body tag but I need to say in function I need to scroll to the top of item after 100px from top of the page.
Here is my code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".scroll").click(function(event){     
        event.preventDefault();
        var x = $(this.hash).offset().top;
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:x},2000);
    });
});
```

Comment: `scrollTop:x` -> `scrollTop:x - 100`?

Comment: @Sarma check my answer please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just adding 100px to `$(this.hash).offset().top` will do it if I understand you correctly.

Since, offset is getting data relative to the document.

> Get the current coordinates of the first element, or set the coordinates of every element, in the set of matched elements, relative to the document. http://api.jquery.com/offset/

## Example:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".scroll").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var x = $(this).offset().top;
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: x - 100 }, 2000);
  });
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="height: 1000px; padding-top: 100px">

<div class="scroll">click to scroll to me</div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Sarma I've written a snippet for you. I don't know exactly what you're trying to solve but this seems working. Notice that I've removed ```$(this.hash)``` for my example to work. You can add it back if you need it.

Comment: I needed to add - LOL not +

Comment: It is not like you answered me because you answered me something I tried with + and not with - but i ll accept it.

Comment: @Sarma Thx, as I say I also forgot editing it while we were talking.